# Using the PDF file names and coordinates for camelot and getting the table details

Tags: python, pdf, python-camelot

I have the pdf images in a column in excel along with its camelot coordinates each one of them in respective rows, a brief look is below :-

```
file_name                             X1_Camelot    Y1_Camelot       x2_Camelot     Y2_Camelot
path/to/pdf_file/folder/1.pdf           16            77                 80           540
path/to/pdf_file/folder/2.pdf           20            300                40           260
path/to/pdf_file/folder/3.pdf           40            90                 200          340
path/to/pdf_file/folder/4.pdf           20            50                 100          440
```

I want to write a python script where it goes to each pdf file take each of its coordinates of camelot version and then place values into below function :-

tables = camelot.read_pdf('table_regions.pdf', table_regions=['170,370,560,270'])
tables[0].df

I want result for each of the PDF from the input csv file having these columns.

I tried using for loop and df.iterrows() but it did not worked.

Comment: Could you show what for-loop you tried? I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be possible using that, if you show me what you tried, I can fix it :)

Comment: import camelot

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    image_name = row['full_path']
    x1_cam = row['X1_Camelot']
    x2_cam = row['X2_Camelot']
    y1_cam = row['Y1_camelot']
    y2_cam = row['Y2_camelot']
    tables = camelot.read_pdf('table_regions.pdf', table_regions=[x1_cam, y1_cam, x2_cam, y2_cam])
    table_details = tables[0].df1
    print(table_details)

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('data.csv', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().split('\n')[1:]
    for line in data:
        fields = line.split(',')
        path = fields[0]
        x1,y1,x2,y2 = int(fields[1]),int(fields[2]),int(fields[3]),int(fields[4])
```